# Why does this double mutex lock not cause deadlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, deadlock

I test c++11 mutex in my centos computer.  I try to double lock this mutex to make deadlock. But after I run it, everything is fine and no deadlock occurs.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
std::mutex m;
int main()
{
  m.lock();
  m.lock();
  std::cout<<"i am ok"<<std::endl;

  return 0;  
}
```

The compiler is g++ 4.8.5 in centos 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64:

```
[zzhao010@localhost shareLibPlay]$ ./3.out
i am ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For a deadlock, you need at least two

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), a deadlock involves at least 2 parties. This was laid down by many authors, among others [Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare) in his pioneering work *Communicating Sequential Processes*.  This is also reminded in the C++ standard definitions (emphasis is mine):

> **17.3.8:** Deadlock: one or more threads are unable to continue execution because
> each is blocked waiting for one or more **of the others** to satisfy some
> condition

A more illustrative definition is given by Anthony Williams, in *C++ concurrency in action*

> Neither thread can proceed, because each is waiting for the other to release it's mutex.  This scenario is called deadlock and it's the biggest problem with having to lock two or more mutexes.

You can therefore by definition not create a deadlock with a single thread in a single process.

#### Don't misunderstand the standard

The standard says on mutexes:

> **30.4.1.2.1/4** [Note: A program may deadlock if the thread that owns a mutex object calls lock() on that object.]

This is a non-normative note.  I think it embarrassingly contradicts the standard's own definition. From the terminology point of view, a process that locks itself is in a blocked state.

But more important, and beyond the issue of deadlock terminology,  the word "MAY" allows the said behavior for C++ implementations (e.g. if it is not able on a particular OS to detect a redundant lock acquisition).  But it's not required at all : I believe that most mainstream C++ implementation will work fine, exactly as you have experienced yourself.

#### Want to experience with deadlocks ?

If you want to experience with real deadlocks, or if you want simply to find out if your C++ implementation is able to detect the `resource_deadlock_would_occur` error, here a short example.  It could go fine but has high probability of creating a deadlock:

```
std::mutex m1,m2;
void foo() {
    m1.lock();
    std::cout<<"foo locked m1"<<std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
    m2.lock();
    m1.unlock(); 
    std::cout<<"foo locked m2 and releases m1"<<std::endl;
    m2.unlock(); 
    std::cout<<"foo is ok"<<std::endl;
}
void bar() {
    m2.lock();
    std::cout<<"bar locked m2"<<std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
    m1.lock();
    m2.unlock(); 
    std::cout<<"barlocked m1 and releases m2"<<std::endl;
    m1.unlock(); 
    std::cout<<"bar is ok"<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(foo); 
    bar(); 
    t1.join(); 
    std::cout << "Everything went fine"<<std::endl; 
    return 0;  
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/IuYh8n)

This kind of deadlock is avoided by locking the different mutexes always in the same order.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker the question is about deadlock.  So this answer perfectly well the question:  the OP's code snippet doesn't create a  deadlock and explains what a deadlock is.   Would OP have asked why his code does'nt wait forver then I would agree with you.

Comment: Looks like the C++ Standard got it wrong when it says "[Note: A program may deadlock if the thread that owns a mutex object calls lock() on that object...." [thread.mutex.class]/4. Or, gosh, maybe there is a broader meaning to "deadlock" than the one on Wikipedia. Regardless, the question is clearly about why the code in the question doesn't lock up, not about whether some other code might end up in a deadlock.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think that deadlock is a term much older than the C++11 standard, and I'm pretty sure that when C.Hoare wrote in 1985 in *Communicating Sequential Processes*, his pioneering work on concurrent programming, "any network of nonstopping processes which is free of cycles cannot deadlock", he was really not considering a single process thread to be able to deadlock.  In fact he calls this single thread blocking a "STOP" -- Please note that I'm not shouting, but Hoare is uses a systematic uppercase for this state name).

Comment: @PeteBecker I edited my answer to clarify my point, this time using C++ standard's own definition

Comment: This is a poor reading of the definition.  If I am waiting for little green men from Mars to take me to outer space, I am not actually presupposing that little green men from Mars actually exist.  Similarly, the fact that a thread is waiting for some other thread to release the resource it is waiting to acquire does not presuppose that another thread actually exists.  The reading of Hoare's text is similarly poor, since a graph in general can contain loops.  The reason these cases are rarely explicitly called out in text is just because they aren't particularly interesting.

Comment: @DietrichEpp i think that I have a rigorous understanding of the definition, knowing that standard doesn't refer to green mens and that the choice of words is carefully weighted by dozen of people. If a self lock would fit in the definition, they would have simplified it to: "one or more threads are unable to continue execution because each is blocked" getting rid of the "others". Moreover many other definitions of "deadlock" are similarly expecting several threads.

Comment: Even if we disagree about the definition of deadlock, this answer still misinterprets the intent of the question.  It is a good example of why Stack Overflow has a reputation for being hostile to new users.

Comment: @DietrichEpp it has the reputation of being hostile because of wild downvotes. This question was at -3 before  i edited it slightly to make itmore acceptable and upvoted it because of the interesting misunderstanding on deadlocks. Now it catched back to 0. I agree that there are several views on this question. However i find it unfair to downvote my contribution because i provide another (argumented) viewpoint

Answer (score 14):

Locking a `std::mutex` that is already locked by the same thread is *undefined behavior* and therefore it may work, it may fail, it may drink all your beer and throw up on the couch.  No guarantees.

Comment: Could you please give a reference in the standard ?  I couldn't find evidence of undefined behavior in mutex section 30.4.1.2.1.

Comment: @Christophe: Please give the full reference instead of just section number.  There are many versions of the standard.

Comment: @Christophe: n3690 §30.4.1.2 ¶7 "Requires: If `m` is of type `std::mutex` ..., the calling thread does not own the mutex."

Answer (score 10):

The behavior is undefined in case you invoke `lock` twice as you did.
*It works as you would expect it to do* is a valid undefined behavior indeed.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock) for further details.